# why can't hide slug field in django admin?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

when i try to exclude 'slug' field in django admin form,i got this msg: "KeyError at /admin/post/post/add/
"Key 'slug' not found in 'PostForm'. Choices are: author, content, image, title."
why?
django code:
model: `models.py` :

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.urls import reverse

# Create your models here.
class Post(models.Model):
    title= models.CharField(max_length=50,null=False,blank=False)
    content= models.TextField(max_length=2000,null=False,blank=False)
    image= models.ImageField( upload_to="post-img/")
    created_at=models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author=models.CharField(max_length=50,null=True,blank=True)
    slug=models.SlugField(max_length=30)
    

    

    class Meta:
        verbose_name =("Post")
        verbose_name_plural =("Posts")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("PostDetail", kwargs={'slug': self.slug})

    def headline(self):
        return self.content[:50]+'...'
```

`admin.py` :

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Post

# Register your models here.


class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    exclude=('created_at','slug',)
    # fieldsets=(({'fields':('title','content','image',)}),)
    
    list_display=['title','headline','author','created_at']
    prepopulated_fields = {'slug': ('title',)}

    
admin.site.register(Post,PostAdmin)
```

thank you !

Comment: It's look like you have done some change on your model without do some migrations. `./manage.py makemigrations` and `./manage.py migrate`. And try again

Comment: Because you added 'slug field' to 'prepopulated_fields'

Comment: The problem is that you excluded the 'slug' field in the admin model registration and then used the 'slug' field in the prepopulated_fields.  You cannot exclude and then use it. It is illogical!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
slug=models.SlugField(max_length=30, blank=True, editable=False)
```

## Note:

Don't set `null` on CharField.`blank` is enough.

you can add the `slug field` to `readonly_fields` in the admin

Answer (score 0):

You have chosen to exclude it from the admin. But it is required by the database to have a value.

You need to add `null=True` and `blank=True` to the field:

```py
slug=models.SlugField(max_length=30, blank=True,  null=True)
```

> *Note: Ensure you `makemigrations` and `migrate` for this to take effect*

See [**Django Docs: ModelAdmin options**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.exclude)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you excluded the 'slug' field in the admin model registration and then used the 'slug' field there in the prepopulated_fields. You cannot exclude and then use it. It is illogical!